# conditional formatting not all options

Tags: excel, macos

I used conditional formatting a while back and had a option called Number which I used to change something to "" (blank). That was at work. Now I am on my macbook and am using excel for mac and when I try to use conditional formatting I only have 3 options on custom formats. Font, Border and Fill. Is there a way to enable more advanced optons or are some options missing in excel for mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Excel for Mac is still a very inferior product compared to Excel for Windows and a lot of features that have been in Excel for Windows for a while are not available in Excel for Mac. Excel for Mac is about where Excel for Windows was in version 2007.

Conditional formatting with Number formats was introduced with Excel 2010 for Windows, IIRC. I can't find any documentation that this can be created on a Mac, so chances are that Excel for Mac can't do this.

Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: Is it possible to get excel for windows on a mac? or do I need to change os. could I use vm?

Comment: I'm not a Mac person, but you can use Parallels or Bootcamp to install a Windows virtual machine on the Mac. All the software you use in the VM would need to be under a Windows license, of course.